# How to count sales in database via sql query vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, count

How can I count the total sales of this table

table name: sales
table columns: roomnum, date, rate, agent, sales_amount

I want to count the sales column under date column.

By single date or range dates.

So far I figure out how to count the number of sales via dates

```
con.Open()
        sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Number of Rows' FROM sales where [date] = ?"
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))

        Dim count As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        check.Text = count.ToString
        con.Close()
```

Now I wanted to figure out how I can calculate the sales via date also.

Thanks

Comment: Your question covers a large scope. COuld you narrow it down to the part you need help with ? Is it with the SQL query, or is it with the VB.NET data access framework (which you don't mention by the way) ?

Comment: I have tried to count how many sales were made, but I coudn't figure out how much sales is made. I count the number of sales made via the dates above.

Comment: Hold on. I will paste my code above.

Comment: @mrlucmorin - its the sql querry to return the total sales made under the column sales with filter to dates

Comment: you can use SUM(sales_amount) instead of COUNT(*) to get the total amount of sales

Comment: Do you want to count the number of sales, or to get the total sold amount in money unit ?

Comment: @Mojoo, thanks now I know the term. Sorry to bother you guys, I am really new to SQL and VB.net. mrlucmorin, im trying to count the total sold amount in money.

Comment: @Mojooo - thanks it works, now with I do the date range, should I stick to between querry?

Comment: @NimitzEBatiocoJr. Count or sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
con.Open()
sql = "SELECT SUM(sales_amount) as 'TotalSold' FROM sales where [date] BETWEEN ? AND ?"
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", fromdate)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", todate)

Dim total As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
check.Text = total.ToString
con.Close()
```

Where `fromdate` and `todate` are defined as DateTime variables.

Also, I used Decimal, but I don't know the data type in the table. Adapt to your needs.

Cheers

Comment: thank you so much. I will search for the other details.